# Second yaxis plotly does not apply

Tags: r, plotly

Hey I am using the package `plotly` to create diagrams and i am trying to set up 2 different yaxis, but it does not work. Here is my code:

```
Schuldenquote_Argentinien <- c(80.3,70.8,62.1,53.8,55.4,43.5,38.9,40.4,43.5,44.7,52.6,53.1,57.1)
Schuldenquote_Brasilien <- c(68.7,65.9,63.8,61.9,65,63.1,61.2,62.2,60.2,62.3,72.6,78.3,84.1)
Schuldenquote_Chile <- c(7,5,3.9,4.9,5.8,8.6,11.1,11.9,12.7,15,17.3,21,23.5)
Schuldenquote_Mexico <- c(38.5,37.4,37.2,42.5,43.7,42,42.9,42.7,45.9,48.9,52.8,56.8,54)
Schuldenquote_Peru <- c(40,34.8,31.9,27.9,28.4,25.4,23,21.2,20,20.7,24,24.5,25.4)

Schulden_Argentinien <- c(159783,0,0,0,0,184396,0,0,0,0,337657,0,367360)*1000000
Schulden_Brasilien <- c(610776,0,0,0,0,1391222,0,0,0,0,1306199,0,1726603)*1000000
Schulden_Chile <- c(8.6,0,0,0,0,18.67,0,0,0,0,42.131,0,65.395)*1000000000
Schulden_Mexico <- c(337621,0,0,0,0,443485,0,0,0,0,618382,0,625687)*1000000
Schulden_Peru <- c(29923,0,0,0,0,37706,0,0,0,0,46037,0,54448)*1000000

Einwohner_Argentinien <- c(39.1455,0,0,0,0,41.2239,0,0,0,0,43.4178,0,44.271)*1000000
Einwohner_Brasilien <- c(186.1974,0,0,0,0,196.7963,0,0,0,0,205.9621,0,209.2883)*1000000
Einwohner_Chile <- c(16.1471,0,0,0,0,16.9934,0,0,0,0,17.7627,0,18.0547)*1000000
Einwohner_Mexico <- c(108.4722,0,0,0,0,117.3189,0,0,0,0,125.8909,0,129.1633)*1000000
Einwohner_Peru <- c(27.6104,0,0,0,0,29.3736,0,0,0,0,31.3767,0,32.1655)*1000000

Schuldenkopf_Argentinien <- Schulden_Argentinien/Einwohner_Argentinien
Schuldenkopf_Brasilien <- Schulden_Brasilien/Einwohner_Brasilien
Schuldenkopf_Chile <- Schulden_Chile/Einwohner_Chile
Schuldenkopf_Mexico <- Schulden_Mexico/Einwohner_Mexico
Schuldenkopf_Peru <- Schulden_Peru/Einwohner_Peru

library(lubridate)
Jahr <- c("01/01/2005","01/01/2006","01/01/2007","01/01/2008","01/01/2009","01/01/2010","01/01/2011","01/01/2012","01/01/2013","01/01/2014","01/01/2015","01/01/2016","01/01/2017")
Jahr <- as.Date(Jahr, format = "%d/%m/%Y", origin = "1970-01-01")

Schuldenquote_Lateinamerika <- data.frame(Jahr,Schuldenquote_Argentinien,Schuldenquote_Brasilien,Schuldenquote_Chile,Schuldenquote_Mexico,Schuldenquote_Peru)
Schuldenkopf_Lateinamerika <- data.frame(Jahr, Schuldenkopf_Argentinien, Schuldenkopf_Brasilien, Schuldenkopf_Chile, Schuldenkopf_Mexico, Schuldenkopf_Peru)
names(Schuldenquote_Lateinamerika) <- c("Jahr","ARG","BRA","CHL","MEX","PER")
names(Schuldenkopf_Lateinamerika) <- c("Jahr","ARG","BRA","CHL","MEX","PER")

library(plotly)
Schulden_Plot <- plot_ly(data = Schuldenkopf_Lateinamerika, y = ~ARG, x = ~Jahr, name = "ARG", type = "bar", color = toRGB("cornflowerblue")) %>%
                        add_trace(y = ~BRA, name = "BRA", marker = list(color = toRGB("forestgreen"))) %>%
                        add_trace(y = ~CHL, name = "CHL", marker = list(color = toRGB("firebrick1"))) %>%
                        add_trace(y = ~MEX, name = "MEX", marker = list(color = toRGB("gold2"))) %>%
                        add_trace(y = ~PER, name = "PER", marker = list(color = toRGB("darkorchid"))) %>%
                        add_lines(y = Schuldenquote_Lateinamerika$ARG, name = " ", mode = "lines", line = list(color = toRGB("cornflowerblue"), width = 2, yaxis = "y2")) %>%
                        add_lines(y = Schuldenquote_Lateinamerika$BRA, name = " ", mode = "lines", line = list(color = toRGB("forestgreen"), width = 2, yaxis = "y2")) %>%
                        add_lines(y = Schuldenquote_Lateinamerika$CHL, name = " ", mode = "lines", line = list(color = toRGB("firebrick1"), width = 2, yaxis = "y2")) %>%
                        add_lines(y = Schuldenquote_Lateinamerika$MEX, name = " ", mode = "lines", line = list(color = toRGB("gold2"), width = 2, yaxis = "y2")) %>%
                        add_lines(y = Schuldenquote_Lateinamerika$PER, name = " ", mode = "lines", line = list(color = toRGB("darkorchid"), width = 2, yaxis = "y2")) %>%
                        layout(yaxis = list(title = "Schulden pro Kopf in USD", linewidth = 3), yaxis2 = list(side = "right", title = "Schulden in Relation zum GDP" , linewidth = 3, overlaying = "y"), xaxis = list(zerolinewidth = 2), barmode = "group", showlegend = FALSE, autosize = TRUE)
Schulden_Plot
```

I tried several different ways to implement it in the code, but I am probably missing something?

Comment: We need a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: I added my full code. You can just copy and paste to run it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you used wrong argument position `yaxis` should be outside the `line = list`.

Additionally, I adjust the margin to looks clear.

Full code is shown below :

```
Schulden_Plot <- plot_ly(data = Schuldenkopf_Lateinamerika, y = ~ARG, x = ~Jahr, name = "ARG", type = "bar", color = toRGB("cornflowerblue")) %>%
  add_trace(y = ~BRA, name = "BRA", marker = list(color = toRGB("forestgreen"))) %>%
  add_trace(y = ~CHL, name = "CHL", marker = list(color = toRGB("firebrick1"))) %>%
  add_trace(y = ~MEX, name = "MEX", marker = list(color = toRGB("gold2"))) %>%
  add_trace(y = ~PER, name = "PER", marker = list(color = toRGB("darkorchid"))) %>%
  add_lines(y = Schuldenquote_Lateinamerika$ARG, name = " ", mode = "lines", line = list(color = toRGB("cornflowerblue"), width = 2), yaxis = "y2") %>%
  add_lines(y = Schuldenquote_Lateinamerika$BRA, name = " ", mode = "lines", line = list(color = toRGB("forestgreen"), width = 2), yaxis = "y2") %>%
  add_lines(y = Schuldenquote_Lateinamerika$CHL, name = " ", mode = "lines", line = list(color = toRGB("firebrick1"), width = 2), yaxis = "y2") %>%
  add_lines(y = Schuldenquote_Lateinamerika$MEX, name = " ", mode = "lines", line = list(color = toRGB("gold2"), width = 2), yaxis = "y2") %>%
  add_lines(y = Schuldenquote_Lateinamerika$PER, name = " ", mode = "lines", line = list(color = toRGB("darkorchid"), width = 2), yaxis = "y2") %>%
  layout(margin = list(l=50, r= 50, b= 50, t= 50),yaxis = list(title = "Schulden pro Kopf in USD", linewidth = 3),
         yaxis2 = list(side = "right", title = "Schulden in Relation zum GDP" , linewidth = 3, overlaying = "y"),
         xaxis = list(zerolinewidth = 2), barmode = "group", showlegend = FALSE, autosize = TRUE)
```

[image]